# Trying to send a simple message back to chat through bot framework activityhandler

Tags: python, python-3.x, botframework

I have a simple Activity Handler below built off Microsoft example code.  It just takes an ip address that the user gives it in chat.  Then I send it to another python file, that part works.

```
from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, TurnContext
from botbuilder.schema import ChannelAccount
import HeartbeatInteractive

class MyBot(ActivityHandler):
    
    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        
        if turn_context.activity.text.startswith('device'):
            search_word = str(turn_context.activity.text)
            ip = search_word.strip().split()[1]
            HeartbeatInteractive.init(ip)
```

The problem is I want to send updates back into the chat as my code finds information related to this IP address.  What would be the best way of doing that?

Should my other python file import the MyBot class and reference some new function to pass a message back? Or do I try to send the message directly to the chat from a new activity handler in the other python file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing anything complicated you can just send an activity after getting the data. The Botbuilder-Samples Python sample, 02.echo-bot, demonstrates sending an activity from the `on_message_activity` activity handler (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/python/02.echo-bot/bots/echo_bot.py#L16)). In your case, your code would sit just above the `send_activity() in which you would include whatever data you received`.

Just be aware that if you're making a call to a service (yours or someone else's) that will take longer than 15 secs to process, then you will want to utilize sending the returned data via a [proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python). Assuming you are using DirectLine, the channel connector will timeout after 15 secs if no response is returned in that time frame. To get around this, simply send a follow up activity stating "I'm working on getting your data" or something similar. Then handle the returned data was it arrives.